How to get rid of shellac finish drips and tide marks?
Newbie here. My first project involving shellac finish.
Got dewaxed garnet shellac flakes, mixed with denatured alcohol I think to a 2ish lb. cut. Applied it using soft China bristle brush on (I assume) Cherry cabinets in kitchen. Applied 5-6 coats.
Applied them in place. Which is to say - I didn't take all cabinets off and lay them flat. Just a couple.
I cleaned the cabinets with DA before applying the shellac.
The ones I polished, while they were upright, look good except for occasional drip marks on a few.
The cabinet that I took off and laid flat came out blotchy at the ends.
Pics of both attached


Q: How to get rid of Shellac drips and blotchiness after 12 hours of last shellac coat?
Here's what I tried so far that didn't work -
- sanding with 0000 sand wool
- Brushing gently with DA

I haven't tried sanding yet. (Nor did I sand between coats, which I think now was a mistake. But easily fixable I assume.)
What are my options at this point?
If sanding is an option, can I use orbital sander and which # grit?
I want to keeping stripping and redo as a last option.
PS: I am planning to eventually put a wipe on top coat (still deciding which one though).

This is why one doesn't generally finish with shellac by brushing alone, at least not on complex surfaces and also why good lighting and careful scrutiny are vital to a good finishing result — you would have caught all this sooner when it was easier to deal with. There's other stuff going on here, including appropriate brush control, brushing methodology and possibly the correct cut to use.

"Nor did I sand in-between coats, Which I think of it now, was a mistake." Not so much. After the first coat (of nearly any finish) it's often helpful because the first coat can raise the grain, but after that it's not necessary, and especially on a melding finish like shellac or lacquer it's counterproductive. "But easily fixable I assume" Yes. If one needs to sand doing it all in one go at the end is often better. And when you need to sand to level you use paper backed by a hard block, not a softer or conformable sanding block and definitely not with the paper backed only by the fingers.

It'll be relevant for all future projects so I'll ask this too, can you post a photo of the brush you used, or a link to it online? The 'new' standard for ideal shellac brush is golden nylon AKA taklon and for the brush to not really be designed for maximum capacity. A good belly or reservoir is great for any finish except for those that dry as fast as shellac does.

I used mostly "Wooster Brush Z3215-2". Link - https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000I1TGWO". Also used "3-inch Purdy Chinex Elite" but reverted back to Wooster due to better area/brush size compatibility

Thanks @Graphus for the suggestion. I now think, the problem is many folds - I started with 1.5lb cut but Shellac in the pail got thicker as time progressed. And not using an ideal brush. I'll strip damaged areas and start with your suggested Taklon brush. Thanks again.

Welcome! Yes the fast evaporation of alcohol means one must not leave a large volume exposed during work as of course the cut will change over time (and quite quickly). This is one of the chief advantages of using a 'rubber' or pad to apply shellac, since the main body of the shellac stays in the covered container and only a small amount is doled out each time the pad is recharged. Link To continue by brush, here is an affordable brush to try, this style.

I don’t have an answer for why your vertical surfaces ended up better finished than the horizontal ones. Could it be that you used a different procedure? (Different drying time, more shellac applied?)
Regardless, to me the outcome looks like a thicker coat resulting in streaks and unevenness.
In my experience, a thinner solution applied in thinner layers gives a more uniform result. I would try something closer to a 1-1.5 lb cut (needs more layers though, maybe 7-8). And does your brush put a lot of shellac on the surface? A lighter touch (plus lifting the brush gently as you approach an edge) or switching to a cotton applicator could help. Also, avoid going back to areas recently coated until they are fully dry.
As for fixing this, I would first sand away any protruding ridges with P220 or so (hitting them with DA could also work). Then apply more coats on top (following the suggestions above). You should get a more uniform finish with each coat as it melds into the previous ones.

Nor did I sand in-between coats, Which I think of it now, was a mistake.

I used to sand between coats of shellac but I don’t think it does much if they are well applied. The only reason to do it would be to get rid of the raised grain, and only once — say, after the 2nd or 3rd coat. Further coats eventually subsume any remaining irregularities.
