Water based paint over dewaxed shellac finish
I recently applied dewaxed Garnet shellac finish over wood kitchen cabinets.
Finish was made by mixing dewaxed shellac flakes in denatured alcohol (DN). 2 lbs cut.
I prepped the cabinets by

Sanding with 000 and 0000 steel wool
cleaning every bit of it with DN.

I, then put some 15+ coats of shellac Finish. Came out smooth and shiny. It's only a month old. No varnish or anything put on top of this shellac finish
Now, I'm considering to paint it over with SW Emerald Urethane Trim Enamel. This water-based enamel paint.
I understand anything will stick to dewaxed shellac finish. So, here is my question -
What prep work do I need to do to apply this (water based) paint on kitchen cabinets which has been finished with dewaxed shellac?
Thank you for your time.
Background added a day after question is asked
Kitchen cabinet, for me, was supposed to be just a dewaxed shellac project. And maybe clear varnish as a top coat. Maybe. I got excited that I don't need to worry about the compatibility with current coat when it comes to dewaxed shellac. I don't know what's on the cabinet currently and a couple of cabinets above stove, were too greasy that even lacquer thinner (suggested by local hardware store) couldn't take it out effectively. I got garnet flakes to impart brownish color to my relatively light brown looking wood cabinets. Instead, what I finally got after so many shellac coats is orange color. While finishing, shellac in the pail turned to a heavier cut and I didn't mind since I was not achieving the color that I wanted. And that introduced lap marks. My research says that eventual coat of shellac would dissolve previous but it didn't for me. Brushing with plain denatured alcohol didn't get rid of lap marks either. Also, somewhere, I sanded one of the cabinet, before coating, with an orbital sander using 220 grits and that spiral lines became prominent after I put shellac coats.
I could strip shellac and start over but not confident enough that I'll do a whole lot better this time. I've no experience in tinting shellac either. Hence, the paint. I'm assuming that hand scuffing with 000 steel wool + cleaning with Denatured alcohol is enough prep but again, doesn't hurt to check with experts. Hence the question.

Hi Raman, this is likely going to be closed as a duplicate. But I wanted to check something, you've obviously looked into this already or you wouldn't know the truism that anything sticks to shellac, I'm just curious did nothing you came across mention whether you needed to prep the shellac surface prior to the next finish going on? Or how to do an adhesion test, to check whether this was needed? Anyway, regardless of these points, basic keying of the surface seems prudent, in a belt-and-braces sort of way.

Hello Graphus, Here's a TL;DR version: I'm a newbie who has done extensive research and youtube offers contradicting ideas sometimes, that helps brew more confusion. For example, an expert may still leave few unanswered questions for my use case. Coupled with failed current project with shellac that I've had so far led me to check on here. Thank you for the link. It is helpful.
I've added background to my OP as there's a word limit here.

@RamanKathpalia the background you added alludes to a different question, which is how to avoid drip marks etc with shellac. Some of that was answered here: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/15446/how-to-get-rid-of-shellac-finish-drips-and-tide-marks

Oh, never mind. It was you who asked ‍♂️

You can ask about many of the separate issues you had along the way, but diligent research would eventually bring up the solutions or answers you sought. "My research says that eventual coat of shellac would dissolve previous but it didn't for me." This is pretty much exclusively for padding on shellac, so at least a basic French polishing technique. Pads (suitably lubricated) allow the application tool to work over the surface as it is softened by the alcohol flattening and burnishing as it goes. It's still quite hard to get anything more than minor irregularities out purely by this method.

.....and obviously it's completely irrelevant to brush application, since of course the brush A, can't be lubricated in the same manner, B, can't press down very hard due to the spring in the bristles. Traditional, old-school, advice based on teaching proper French polishing technique will largely focus on how to minimise or avoid textural issues for this reason, which of course doesn't help anyone who has already found themselves with heavy brush marks, drips etc. So, ignoring that advice is then advisable — you simply scrape or sand to get the surface flat or flatter, then proceed again.

On the colour, dark shellac was never going to give you the colour you wanted, with any reasonable number of coats. Major colour revisions are the realm of stain, or coloured overcoats (with added dyes and/or pigment), not a purely translucent resin that acts more like coloured glass (and compare the thicknesses of stained glass to even seven to a dozen coats of shellac.... no comparison). But instead, a single coat of "gel stain" might have been enough to get to the colour you wanted + coats can be stacked to go to darker and darker if needed, but at the cost of obscuring the wood.

Degreasing. To degrease really thoroughly lacquer thinner would eventually get you there if you do it right (to avoid simply spreading grease around). But at scale this is costly. If you must avoid using water (arguably prudent) it's much easier to rely on physical removal (basically, scraping) to get any gross amounts off, then do the bulk of the chemical degreasing using mineral spirits which is a very effective grease cutter & generally much cheaper. Then at the end if you wanted to give it one last degreasing pass using a 'dry' solvent you'd go with e.g. lacquer thinner, acetone, xylene.

Final product - Paint came out smooth and looks good. I think - Shellac as base layer underneath has lot to contribute to smoothness of paint. I'll use the shellac knowledge I gained on my next project.
Thanks a lot for all the help I received here.
